# Always resize the viewStack

Tags: apache-flex, viewstack

I'm facing one weird problem : I'm using a viewStack which have is property `resizeToContent` set to `true`. When I'm selecting a child higher than the viewStack, it's correctly resized, but when I'm selecting another child which is smaller, the viewStack isn't resized !!!
What I want is that my viewStack get the `height` of the `selectedChild` each time.

though, the Adobe doc say :

> If true, the ViewStack container automatically resizes to the size of its current child.

Have any idea ???

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you setting a height on the ViewStack? And what do you mean when you talk about "selecting" a child "higher than the viewstack"? Selecting doesn't mean resizing.

Comment: Can't reproduce based on your description. Can you provide the code that is causeing this? Please keep it simple so that we can copy/paste it into our IDE and try it out.

Comment: 1 - Yes, I'm setting a height="100%" to my viewStack
2 - I mean that, first I'm displaying a view (the first per default) with let say height="x". Then, I'm displaying another view which have a height="y" with y > x, so my viewStack adapt its height="y". And the, I'm displaying another view which have a height="z" with z < y and then my viewStack keep the height="y".
- for provide the code, it's the simple code fro a viewStack and 3 components to be display when I'm selecting the index I want...

Answer (score 0):

So...,

as I haven't found any solution, I take a work around : I'm setting a default value for the height of my viewStack each time I'm changing the view seleted....
It's not very clean, but it's work

but if someone found a better soluce, I'll be happy :)